# Drag and drop freezes when moving a file from desktop to a folder using Nautilus. (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, nautilus-actions

Sometimes, when I drag and drop files using Nautilus on Ubuntu 16.04, the mouse freezes on the grab state. Restarting the Nautilus fixes the problem.

Comment: This is bug 1740599.  Do visithttps://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1740599  and add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list (click on yellow icon next to question).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the output of this command:

echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

If it says Wayland then that is probably the issue. You can try XORG.

On the off chance that someone on Pop! OS is reading this, logout and use the gear icon to select Pop and not Pop on Wayland.

Comment: thanks! I tired this on Ubuntu 18 and it returns x11 what does it mean?

Comment: It means you are on XORG (X), not Wayland... and you still experience the issue?

Comment: Thanks, could you please also edit your answer to include the X** output? Is 11 the version of the XORG? thanks.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, using Xorg (X11) and I do also encounter this issue. Only since yesterday though.

Answer (score 0):

It happens in `Ubuntu 20.10` also.
Tried changing between: `Ubuntu` (X11)/`Ubuntu Wayland` without success.

### Solution

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences use-experimental-views false
```

### Note

Disabling experimental views option is no longer available in `Nautilus->Preferences`

[Nautilus Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvRys.png)

Then reboot. Can use both graphic engines without issues.