# Input methods stop working after drag&drop from desktop to application

Tags: gnome-shell

When I try to drag a file from to desktop to let's say a browser or terminal, the mouse get's stuck in the "hand" position, the keyboard stops working, as well as the mouse (I can still move it around but that's about it). The only thing that gets rid of the problem (so far), is restarting gdm, e.g. `sudo service gdm restart` from a TTY.

I've read about some similar issues [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023467/drag-and-drop-freezes-when-moving-a-file-from-desktop-to-a-folder-using-nautilus), but my `XDG_SESSION_TYPE` seems to be `x11`.

I opened a `tail -f` on `/var/log/syslog`, tried to drag&drop a file, and this is the important output (I think):

```
Dec  4 11:38:07 ublin gnome-shell[6492]: value "inf" of type 'gfloat' is invalid or out of range for property 'x' of type 'gfloat'
Dec  4 11:38:07 ublin gnome-shell[6492]: value "inf" of type 'gfloat' is invalid or out of range for property 'y' of type 'gfloat'
Dec  4 11:38:07 ublin gnome-shell[6492]: value "-nan" of type 'gdouble' is invalid or out of range for property 'scale-x' of type 'gdouble'
Dec  4 11:38:07 ublin gnome-shell[6492]: value "-nan" of type 'gdouble' is invalid or out of range for property 'scale-y' of type 'gdouble'
Dec  4 11:38:07 ublin gnome-shell[6492]: JS ERROR: Error: Argument x: value is out of range for gfloat#012_onAnimationComplete@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/dnd.js:742:27#012onComplete@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/dnd.js:720:22#012_makeEaseCallback/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:84:13#012_easeActor/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:165:64
Dec  4 11:38:07 ublin gnome-shell[6492]: clutter_actor_allocate: assertion '!isnan (real_allocation.x1) && !isnan (real_allocation.x2) && !isnan (real_allocation.y1) && !isnan (real_allocation.y2)' failed
Dec  4 11:38:07 ublin gnome-shell[6492]: Can't update stage views actor StWidget is on because it needs an allocation.
Dec  4 11:38:07 ublin gnome-shell[6492]: Can't update stage views actor ClutterClone is on because it needs an allocation.
```

Happy to provide more details and I'm pretty much a noob so I may need to ask how to find certain infos.

Comment: Probably [this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/ShellExtensions/desktop-icons/-/issues/224), already fixed.

Comment: @PabloBianchi donno if **this** issue but it is fixed for me. So keep your system up to date guys :D

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution, but I've now experienced the same problem twice, with the same error messages in journalctl.  Not even restarting gdm helped me, I needed to reboot.

Both times it sure feels like Firefox was the culprit; the second time I was definitely trying to drag-and-drop, but I don't recall what was happening the first time.

- Firefox 83.0
- Ubuntu 20.10
- Linux rg 5.8.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 09:14:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
Dec 12 17:06:18 rg gnome-shell[2704]: clutter_actor_allocate: assertion '!isnan (real_allocation.x1) && !isnan (real_allocation.x2) && !isnan (real_allocation.y1) && !isnan (real_allocation.y2)' failed
Dec 12 17:06:18 rg gnome-shell[2704]: Can't update stage views actor StWidget is on because it needs an allocation.
Dec 12 17:06:18 rg gnome-shell[2704]: Can't update stage views actor ClutterClone is on because it needs an allocation.
Dec 12 17:06:19 rg gnome-shell[2704]: value "inf" of type 'gfloat' is invalid or out of range for property 'x' of type 'gfloat'
Dec 12 17:06:19 rg gnome-shell[2704]: value "inf" of type 'gfloat' is invalid or out of range for property 'y' of type 'gfloat'
Dec 12 17:06:19 rg gnome-shell[2704]: value "-nan" of type 'gdouble' is invalid or out of range for property 'scale-x' of type 'gdouble'
Dec 12 17:06:19 rg gnome-shell[2704]: value "-nan" of type 'gdouble' is invalid or out of range for property 'scale-y' of type 'gdouble'
Dec 12 17:06:19 rg gnome-shell[2704]: JS ERROR: Error: Argument x: value is out of range for gfloat
                                      _onAnimationComplete@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/dnd.js:742:27
                                      onComplete@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/dnd.js:720:22
                                      _makeEaseCallback/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:84:13
                                      _easeActor/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:165:64
Dec 12 17:06:20 rg gnome-shell[2704]: clutter_actor_allocate: assertion '!isnan (real_allocation.x1) && !isnan (real_allocation.x2) && !isnan (real_allocation.y1) && !isnan (real_allocation.y2)' failed
Dec 12 17:06:20 rg gnome-shell[2704]: Can't update stage views actor StWidget is on because it needs an allocation.
Dec 12 17:06:20 rg gnome-shell[2704]: Can't update stage views actor ClutterClone is on because it needs an allocation.
Dec 12 17:06:24 rg gnome-shell[2704]: clutter_actor_allocate: assertion '!isnan (real_allocation.x1) && !isnan (real_allocation.x2) && !isnan (real_allocation.y1) && !isnan (real_allocation.y2)' failed
```